# how to load additional bean configuration file in spring at run time

Tags: spring

I have a spring app, and in the future we will develop more classes, and for these class we will also use additional configuration files (not overwrite the existing ones) to define the beans. Then how to dynamically load them? I know there is an interface of ApplicationContextAware, I could have a bean running checking whether new configuration files are available, if they come, I could run the

```
setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
```

But then how to use ApplicationContext to load the additional configuration file?

**update:**
If the app is loaded from XML then I could convert ApplicationContext to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and then use the load method,but what if AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, it only has scan method to scan package, but what if I want to load from xml?

**update:**
The following is the code I want to use, it used spring integration to monitor a fold, at run time I could put jar file on the class path, and then put the xml configuration in that folder, this will trigger the loadAdditionBeans function to run, and the xml File object will be passed in, what need to do is to add the context in that File to the current context but not create a child context.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;

import java.io.File;

@MessageEndpoint
public class FolderWatcher implements ApplicationContextAware {
    //private ApplicationContext ctx;
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx;  // it's a spring boot,so the ctx is AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx=(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)applicationContext;
    }
    @ServiceActivator
    public void loadAdditionBeans(File file){
        /*
        file is an xml configuration file, how to load the beans defined it into the currect context,
        I don't what to have another hierarchy, since that will make the beans defined in the file not
        available in parent.
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: cann't u load the configuration file on Spring Listener ?

Comment: @SK08, I am new to spring, could you please put more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pmrl = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(context.getClassLoader());
  Resource[] resources = pmrl.getResources(
    "classpath*:com/mycompany/**/applicationContext.xml"
  );

for (Resource r : resources) {
   GenericApplicationContext createdContext = new GenericApplicationContext(context);
   XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(createdContext);
   int i = reader.loadBeanDefinitions(r);
}
```

Have a look at the above code and let me know if it helps to resolve your problem.

Comment: Will you approach load the beans in the root context, or will it create some child context when calling  reader.loadBeanDefinitions(r)? If create child context, then it's a problem for me since root context can't see these beans.

Comment: This is creating a new context. If you want to load it in the root context then pass that as a parameter to XmlBeanDefinitionReader. That should work.

Comment: thanks for your info. And will be it reloaded or just ignore if a bean already exists? Just want to know what will happen if in case there are some confliction.

Comment: Ist really needed to create a new `GenericApplicationContext` inside the loop? Couldn't this context be created outside the loop?

Comment: Creating a new context seems to cause problems, at least in my case. Here is a [working variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46117572/238134) of the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the classpath scanning but you still want o load additional configurations from XML, you can simply use the `@ImportResource` annotation on your `@Configuration` class and import the XML resource you need: 

`@Configuration
@ImportResource( { "classpath*:/rest_config.xml" } )
public class MyConfig{
 ...
}`

That way it's easy to mix in legacy XML configuration with newer, Java configs and you don't have to - for example - migrate your entire configuration in one go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ,You approach only works when the java app startup. After the app start, we need a new approach to dynamically add beans.