# Spring Batch integration - How to get the remote steps that are external to the job visible to the StepLocator on the remote execution JVM?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I've got my jobs configured for remote partitioning, I'm sending the message through kafka, the slave VM is receiving the requests and attempting to kick off the step, but it can't find the step.

It appears that the beanFactory (applicationContext) I am providing does not contain the remote execution step.

I have walked through the example at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU several times, and am missing how the correct beanFactory is identified and set for the slave jobs.

During application initialization, the ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean is loaded from the jobs library, which contains XML for all of the spring batch jobs and the remote slave steps. This bean contains a separate resource for each XML file, including the slave files (as expected), and assigned tothe applicationContext.

```
@Bean
public ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean classpathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean () throws IOException
{
    String resourcePath = configPropertiesService
            .fetchPropertyValue(PropertyValueConstants.MXARCHIVE_SKELETON_LOCATION,
                    PropertyValueConstants.MXARCHIVE_SKELETON_LOCATION_DEFAULT)
            .getValue() + "*.xml";

    logger.trace("classpathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean()  :: {} ", resourcePath);
    Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources(resourcePath);

    ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean bean = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean ();
    bean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    bean.setResources(resources);

    return bean;
}
```

The BeanFactoryStepLocator is initialized with the applicationContext.

```
@Bean
public BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator() throws Exception
{
    BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator = new BeanFactoryStepLocator ();

/* applicationContext is autowired in the postconstruct - what we do here doesn't matter
    stepLocator.setBeanFactory(applicationContext); // TODO: Find the right factory
    */
    return stepLocator;
};

// EDIT: added method to code listing so the calling method is visible
@Bean
public StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler() throws Exception {
    StepExecutionRequestHandler result = new StepExecutionRequestHandler();
    ;

    result.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
    BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator = stepLocator ();
    result.setStepLocator(stepLocator);
    return result;
}
```

On execution, the framework attempts to invoke the step and fails because the step is not present in the application context (beanFactory).

```
Thread-7 2019-04-23 12:47:30,343 INFO  c.m.m.s.DefaultBatchConfigurer - ThreadPoolTaskExecutor status => Active threads :: 1, Total threads ::30, 3.3333333333333335 % Active.
executionContainer-C-1 2019-04-23 12:47:30,966 ERROR o.s.k.l.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = job.step, partition = 0, offset = 47, CreateTime = 1556041503162, serialized key size = 4, serialized value size = 78, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = sequenceNumber, value = [49, 49]), RecordHeader(key = correlationId, value = [34, 49, 55, 57, 49, 58, 102, 115, 45, 115, 116, 101, 112, 48, 48, 48, 50, 46, 115, 108, 97, 118, 101, 34]), RecordHeader(key = sequenceSize, value = [49, 50]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 83, 105, 122, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 114, 114, 101, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = 11, value = StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=1791, stepExecutionId=21396, stepName=fs-step0002.slave])
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'fs-step0002.slave' available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:461) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:369) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$400(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:74) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:431) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:402) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1224) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1217) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1159) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1099) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:934) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:750) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:699) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'fs-step0002.slave' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.BeanFactoryStepLocator.getStep(BeanFactoryStepLocator.java:34) ~[spring-batch-integration-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.StepExecutionRequestHandler.handle(StepExecutionRequestHandler.java:58) ~[spring-batch-integration-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor687.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1119) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:617) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:490) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:313) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

The step XML (sanitized) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-lazy-init="false" > <!-- usual suspects -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <batch:step id="fs-step0002.slave">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
            start-limit="100">
            <batch:chunk reader="myCustomItemReader" writer="myCustomWriter"
                commit-interval="1"/>

        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:fail on="FAILED" />
    </batch:step>
</beans>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I forced the creation of a new ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean that only read the remote step file (and only one of them). It still complains that there is no bean of the expected name, but I can see it is definitely there.

Later, when I trace into the steplocator, I can see that the beanFactory is empty.

Workaround code for testing:

```
@Bean
public ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean stepFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    String resourcePath = configPropertiesService
            .fetchPropertyValue(PropertyValueConstants.MXARCHIVE_SKELETON_LOCATION,
                    PropertyValueConstants.MXARCHIVE_SKELETON_LOCATION_DEFAULT)
            .getValue() + "*slave.xml";

    logger.trace("classpathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean()  :: {} ", resourcePath);
    Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources(resourcePath);

    ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean bean = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean();
    bean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    bean.setResources(resources);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator() throws Exception {

    BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator = new BeanFactoryStepLocator();
    ApplicationContextFactory[] factories = stepFactoryBean().getObject();
    if (factories != null) {         
        stepLocator.setBeanFactory(factories[0].createApplicationContext().getBeanFactory());
    }

    return stepLocator;
};
```

Debugger view of beanFactory within the stepLocator, at time of creation.

[image: Debugger view of beanFactory within the stepLocator]

Debugger View of results of getStep() at end of stepLocator() factory method:

[image: Debugger View of results of getStep() at end of stepLocator() factory method]

**EDIT 2:**

It appears that the original "applicationContext" is autowired as the beanfactory, so the real issue is to load the additional beans into the applicationContext.

I have also tried the solutions suggested at [how to load additional bean configuration file in spring at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580811/how-to-load-additional-bean-configuration-file-in-spring-at-run-time) and linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare the dependency you need to the BeanFactory and let Spring give the right instance instead of you doing the lookup/injection manually. So instead of:

```
@Bean
public BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator() throws Exception {
   BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator = new BeanFactoryStepLocator();
   ApplicationContextFactory[] factories = stepFactoryBean().getObject();
   if (factories != null) {         
      stepLocator.setBeanFactory(factories[0].createApplicationContext().getBeanFactory());
   }
   return stepLocator;
};
```

use something like:

```
@Bean
public StepLocator stepLocator(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    BeanFactoryStepLocator beanFactoryStepLocator = new BeanFactoryStepLocator();
    beanFactoryStepLocator.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    return beanFactoryStepLocator;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already discovered that the beanFactory attribute is autowired with the root application context, overriding anything that we set in the code. At present, the `stepLocator()` method returns only the result of `new BeanFactoryStepLocator()`, autowired with `applicationContext` . As noted, I can see the step bean in the `alreadyCreated` property of the applicationContext, but the stepLocator is unable to find the step.

Comment: I have updated the code snip to show that setting the beanFactory is a red herring.

Comment: Could we set up a meeting so we can look at this together? The problems are not where we are expecting them to be, and I have a tight timeline.  Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to ask your question on the gitter channel of the project (https://gitter.im/spring-batch/Lobby) and the team would be happy to help.